# Center a div with a background, inside topbar with 100% width

Tags: html, css

How do I get the logo centered inside the topbar who has a width of 100%? I feel like a complete idiot lol. margin: 0px auto aint working..

**HTML**

```
<div id="topbar-fullwidth">
        <div class="tb menu" id="unfoldMenu"></div>
        <div class="tb logo"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#topbar-fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tb.menu {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    float: left;
    background: url('../images/icons/unfold_menu@2x.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 22px;
    background-position: 10px 13px;
}

.tb.logo {
    width: 140px;
    height: 44px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    background: url('../images/logo@2x.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 125px;
    background-position: 10px;  
}
```

Thanks lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `margin:0 auto;` on a floated element. So you need to remove `float:left;` on the logo.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Q5PSY/2/)**

Comment: Oh my god, I feel like such a dummy lmfao. Thanks buddy, appreciate it. I will accept your answer within 10 minutes. It wont let me right now.

Comment: @user3512502 I won't say anything because it often happens to me to ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use float: with element that have `margin:0 auto` set.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9WmnV/) is an example I hope it will help, changed background: with background-color to make changes visible. I have also removed float:left.